# Prevent Google Analytics code usage on other domain

Tags: angular, google-analytics

We are planning to use Google Analytics in our Angular application.  We generated GA id and integrated with code successfully.  But we are observing that this code can be used on localhost or other domain.  It means that any malicious team can use this ID and spoil our tracking data.  How do we enforce that this ID can be used from given domain?
thanks in advance